# Text area resize handles and draggable in firefox even with resize: none;

Tags: html, css, firefox

[image: firefox bug]

Anyone seen this before? Simple textarea that I have set to the following CSS:

```
 #discusspostform textarea{
 width: 230px;
 height:25px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:40px;
 left:8px;
 top:5px;
 padding:5px;
 resize:none; 
 }
```

Works okay but if the user doubles click a few times (as they no doubt will!). It gives resize handles and an arrow to drag it around the page.I have drag and drop on the site, but this is not required! Anyway to stop it?

Comment: You must be enabling drag/drop on it with javascript .. What you describe is not the built-in browser resize.. (*the css `resize` property only deals with the built-in resize ability*). Can you post more info about the drag/drop functionality you have in your page ?

Comment: I know what it is I have resize with jquery ui. Probably linked that. Thanks for the pointer will post back with more info or a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this code and it maybe help you, its Javascript.

```
document.execCommand('enableObjectResizing', false, false);
```

Comment: it sorts the handles (resize) but not the drag and drop.